Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'....or one of its dependencies
I have a VB.Net (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8) application I am updating to support SQL Server 2022. The solution contains 7 projects, several of which had a reference for the System.Data.SqlClient package.
I changed the project to remove System.Data.SqlClient and added the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 5.0.0.0 packages thru NuGet. Then, I changed any project referencing System.Data.SqlClient to now reference Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, updated my Imports statements, and changed any code that needed to be changed.
I can debug/run the application in VS2019 successfully, but once I build the solution, and deploy it to another machine, I get this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'
at HL7_Engine.clsReportProcessor.SetupDatabaseAccess()
at HL7_Engine.clsReportProcessor.ProcessReports()

What could I be missing? Do I have to manually install the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient data provider on the deployment machine?
I expected it would be included in my build. I'm not following the disconnect of what I included thru NuGet, referenced, and then supposedly built into my final product.
I tried searching my solution for any use of the System.Data.SqlClient, and only found entries like this in my app.config files:
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>

Can I just replace the "System.Data.SqlClient with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?
